# usb c dp alt mode not working on my laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, multiple-monitors, usb-3.1-type-c

I bought a laptop because it has a type-c display port feature, in order to easily change between my MacBook pro and laptop and work with my external display.

I faced an issue in that the type-c display port doesn't work on my laptop.

The monitor is MSI Optix MAG274QRF QD, the cable is THUNDERBOLT 3 (USB-C) CABLE 0.8M APPLE (MQ4H2ZM/A), the laptop is GIGABYTE G5 KD

When I tried to update all drivers from the official site, I faced new interesting issue.

Prerequisites:

1. My laptop is turned on
2. Monitor is plugged into the laptop by a type-c display port

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download SerialIO-Intel [30.100.2129.8] Nov 09, 2021 driver from the official site.
2. Start and install it.

Right after installing the screen blinks, the Windows sound of the new connected device plays, and the external display start working. If I unplug the monitor, then plug in it again, it doesn't work again. After doing all steps again, it starts working until restarting/turning off the laptop, and unplugging/plugging in the monitor. By the way, the monitor is working fine with my Macbook.

So I came to the conclusion, that it's the software problem, as it works fine after driver installation.

My OS info:

Edition Windows 10 Pro

Version 22H2

Installed on ‎04.‎10.‎2022

OS build 19045.2965

Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what is `SerialIO-Intel` - all references I can find mention SPI and I2C on the Intel-NUC - so, doesn't seem relevant to usb-c alt mode - perhaps you need a windows 10 driver for the USB devices on *a laptop™*

Comment: @JaromandaX As far as I understood from the driver ReadMe it's for the next devices - Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller, Intel(R) Serial IO SPI Host Controller,
 Intel(R) Serial IO UART Host Controller,
 Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller

Comment: none of which has anything to do with USB - so, no surprise installing that driver did nothing

Comment: perhaps the USB3.0 driver on the downloads page for that laptop will improve matters - https://www.gigabyte.com/au/Laptop/G5--Intel-11th-Gen/support#support-dl-driver-usb30

Comment: @JaromandaX why do nothing? after installing it start working for a moment :) USB driver was the first I tried, but only on serialIO driver I noticed some result

Comment: really odd that a intel nuc driver would fix a gigabyte laptop - but - intel is a strange beast

Comment: @JaromandaX any suggestion on where I should dig to find some answers?

Comment: gigabyte support would be my first guess

Comment: (1) Have you tried another cable? (2) Try "Win+Ctrl+Shift+B" to reset the graphics driver. (3) Try disabling the iGPU in device manager.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect your Battery! After hours of searching through blogs, I temporarily disconnected the battery within Bios. Powered the machine back on. Full USB C functionality restored. Youre welcome!

Comment: THANK YOU!!! My new Lenovo Ideapad Pro 5 16APH8 would just not display any output via USB-C, neither under Linux (NixOS, PopOS), nor under Windows. I tried everything. After following your suggestion, it magically worked.